# How do I repeat an edit on multiple lines in Vim?

Tags: vim

I'm aware that in Vim I can often repeat a command by simply adding a number in front of it. For example, one can delete 5 lines by:

```
5dd
```

It's also often possible to specify a range of lines to apply a command to, for example

```
:10,20s:hello:goodbye:gc
```

How can I perform a 'vertical edit'? I'd like to, for example, insert a particular symbol, say a comma, at the beggining (skipping whitespace, i.e. what you'd get if you type a comma after Shift-I in command mode) of every line in a given range. How can this be achieved (without resorting to down-period-down-period-down-period)?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

`:10,20s/^/,/`

Or use a macro, record with:

`q a i , ESC j h q`

use with:

`@ a`

Explanation: `q a` starts recording a macro to register `a`, `q` ends recording. There are registers `a` to `z` available for this.

Comment: Thanks. What if i wanted the equivalent of a shift-i? That is, skipping over the initial whitespace?

Comment: Explanation: `^\(\s*\)` captures initial whitespace and saves it into a register, which you can then read with `\1`.

Comment: Can you use `@ a` multiple times?

Answer (score 181):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> enters visual mode blockwise.  You can then move (<kbd>h</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>l</kbd>-wise, as normal), and if you want to insert something on multiple lines, use <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>i</kbd>.

So for the text:

```
abc123abc
def456def
ghi789ghi
```

if you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> with your cursor over the 1, hit <kbd>j</kbd> twice to go down two columns, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>i</kbd><kbd>,</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd> , your text would look like this:

```
abc,123abc
def,456def
ghi,789ghi
```

(the multi-line insert has a little lag, and won't render until AFTER you hit <kbd>ESC</kbd>).

Comment: Nice.  Ctrl-V means uppercase, by the way, you could say Ctrl-Shift-v

Comment: actually, it's either CTRL-v or CTRL-V.  Vim is case-insensitive for CTRL- codes (see :help CTRL-{char}).

Comment: after searching a bit of why this method wasn't working is because it uses a capital I (shift-i) instead of i (also, it was only ctrl-v, as ctrl-shift-v moved me to the end)

Comment: But, `Ctrl + Shift + v` is paste in the command line and in vim. Isn't it?

Comment: `Ctrl + Shift + v` is paste in X11 many terminal clients (nothing to do with vim, which uses `p` and `P` for paste; neither vim nor the command shell are aware of the X11 clipboard). To get around this, you could use Caps Lock instead of shift to get the capital V. Just remember to turn it off again right afterwards.

Comment: I'm curious. Why don't they just use `i` without the shift key?

Comment: i without shift is insert at current position.  shift + i is insert at beginning of line

Answer (score 72):

That's what the :norm(al) command is for:

```
:10,20 normal I,
```

Answer (score 54):

If you are already using the '.' to repeat your last command a lot, then I found [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip84) to be the most convenient solution so far. It allows you to repeat your last command on each line of a visual block by using

```
" allow the . to execute once for each line of a visual selection
vnoremap . :normal .<CR>
```

Comment: This is helpful but also limited as the `.` operates line wise in visual mode. I think the visual mode in this case can sometimes be convenient to select a line range. But commands and macros are more flexible and powerful in this case.

Answer (score 27):

I believe the easiest way to do this is

1) record a macro for one line, call it 'a'; in this case one types

> q a I , ESC j q

2) select the block of lines that you want to apply the macro to

3) use the 'norm' function to execute macro 'a' over this block of lines, i.e.,

> ```
> :'<,'>norm@a
> ```

Comment: This approach is convenient for repeating more complicated operations.  But note that `:norm` runs significantly slower than `:s` if you have thousands of lines or more.

Answer (score 19):

With your edit already saved in the `.` operator, do the following:

1. Select text you want to apply the operator to using visual mode
2. Then run the command `:norm .`

Comment: This perfectly resolved my issue without needing a macro (i love you)

Comment: Thanks this was great. Another option without visual is just to specify a range, for example `:25-30norm .`. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 18):

I think the easiest is to record a macro, and then repeat the macro as many times as you want. For example to add a comma at the start of every line, you type:

```
q a I , ESC j q
```

to repeat that 5 times, you enter

```
5 @ a
```

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the macros, as already answered, for the specific case of inserting a comma in a range of lines (say from line 10 to 20), you might do something like:

```
:10,20s/\(.*\)/,\1
```

That is, you can create a numbered group match with \( and \), and use \1 in the replacement string to say "replace with the contents of the match".

Answer (score 2):

I use [block visual mode](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Learning_the_vi_editor/Vim/Modes#block_visual_mode). This allows you to perform inserts/edits across multiple lines (aka 'vertical edits').

Comment: your link is broken